# Constructor of a inherited class in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor, inheritance

I am doing a project that contains two classes: Evidence and Image(son of Evidence)

The constructor of Evidence is:

```
Evidence(A* a, B* b, C* c);
```

The constructor of the inherited class Image is:

```
Image(A* a, B* b, C* c): Evidence(a,b,c){... code...}
```

The compiler throws me the following error:

```
In file included from src/evidence/Image.cpp:8:
src/evidence/Image.h:22: error: no matching function for call to
'Evidence::Evidence(A*&, B*&, C*&)'
src/evidence/Evidence.h:35: note: candidates are: Evidence::Evidence(A*, B*, C*)
src/evidence/Evidence.h:21: note: Evidence::Evidence(const Evidence&)
```

What is wrong? I am so confused that I hurt myself.

Comment: Your error says "(A*&, B*&, C*&)" so you need to post the exact code that is giving you the error.

Comment: That's not the exact error you're experiencing: pay attention to the last message: "src/evidence/Image.h:22: error: expected `{' at end of input" You probably have an extra brace in your code, or something like that.

Comment: @Baltasarq that was a copy paste error... That do not affect.

Comment: @doctorlove The error appear exactly in that line... in the definition of the constructor in the cpp file.

Comment: Please create a sscce, like here http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

You *declared* your `Evidence` constructor, but you did not actually *define* it.

Replace:

`Evidence(A* a, B* b, C* c);`

With:

`Evidence(A* a, B* b, C* c) {}`

Comment: Sorry but I just post the declaration of the constructor in the .h In the cpp file the constructor is defined making attribute assignments.